# How to stop cron job after the main program is completed it executing in apscheduler Python

Tags: python, cron, scheduled-tasks, apscheduler

I wanted to use the cron  with BackgroundScheduler, but even after completion of the program the corn task is still getting executed.

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
import time 

def job_function():
    print ("Hello World",time.time())

sched = BackgroundScheduler()

sched.add_job(job_function, 'cron', hour='*',minute='*',second='*/10')
sched.start()
c= 0
while c< 10:
    print("sleeping here")
    time.sleep(5)
    c= c+1
```

The output on the console. Here after the loop terminates the cron task should also end.
I suspect it has to do with daemonic mode as mentioned in [docs](https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler/blob/3.x/examples/schedulers/background.py)
The default for demon parameter is `True`.

And when one should use `sched.shutdown()`?

```
sleeping here
sleeping here
Hello World 1641188360.0097458
sleeping here
sleeping here
Hello World 1641188370.00811
sleeping here
sleeping here
Hello World 1641188380.0121465
sleeping here
sleeping here
Hello World 1641188390.0067406
sleeping here
sleeping here
Hello World 1641188400.0159924
Hello World 1641188410.0143545
Hello World 1641188420.0040658
Hello World 1641188430.0077617
Hello World 1641188440.0112731
Hello World 1641188450.012946
```

Comment: Well, sort of.  `sched.start` starts a background thread.  By default, it starts the background thread as a "daemon", and a daemon thread should terminate when the app terminates.  If there is a non-daemon thread, the process won't die until the last non-daemon thread ends.  Since the default is "daemon", you shouldn't see this unless you've changed the configuration.

Comment: I have not changed the default configuration.
Got it working correctly after having a `sched.shutdown()` after the while loop ends.